# How can I write the array of strings in the Excel file at the same time?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have used this code:

```
public static void write_excel(string[] str)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;
    ObjExcel.Visible = false;
    ObjExcel.UserControl = true;
    ObjExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
    ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Template_Modified.xls");
    ObjWorkSheet = ObjWorkBook.Sheets[2];
    ObjWorkSheet.Cells[4, 4] = str[0];
    ObjWorkSheet.Cells[5, 4] = str[1];
    ObjWorkSheet.Cells[6, 4] = str[2];
    ObjWorkSheet.Cells[7, 4] = str[3];
    ObjWorkBook.Save();
    ObjExcel.Quit();
}

for (int i = 0; i < value1; i++)
{
    TextBox tbx1 = (TextBox)(from t in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>() where t.Name == i.ToString() select t).First();
    str1 = tbx1.Text;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str1))
    {
        arr5[i] = str1;
        write_excel(arr5);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
}

for (int i = val1; i < to_val1; i++)
{
    TextBox tbx2 = (TextBox)(from t2 in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>() where t2.Name == i.ToString() select t2).First();
    str2 = tbx2.Text;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str2))
    {
        arr1[i] = str2;
        write_excel(arr1); // call the function (sent the array of strings)
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
}
```

How can I write the array of strings in the Excel file at the same time?

I have used `TextBox` from C# forms application.

After I have written the text in `TextBox` I have clicked `OK` button, and the text from `TextBox` is sent to the array of strings.

After the array of strings send the text to the function `write_excel()`

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

namespace excel_array_sent
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
            string str = "DNO";
            string str2 = "DNO";
            string str3 = "DNO";
            string str4 = "DNO";
            string str5 = "DNO";

            // Для получения значений равное 4
            int value1_4 = 4;
            int value2_4 = 8;
            int value3_4 = 12;
            int value4_4 = 16;
            int value5_4 = 20;
            string[] arr1_4 = new string[value1_4];
            string[] arr2_4 = new string[value2_4];
            string[] arr3_4 = new string[value3_4];
            string[] arr4_4 = new string[value4_4];
            string[] arr5_4 = new string[value5_4];

            // Для получения значений равное 3
            int value1_3 = 3;
            int value2_3 = 7;
            int value3_3 = 11;
            int value4_3 = 15;
            int value5_3 = 19;
            string[] arr1_3 = new string[value1_3];
            string[] arr2_3 = new string[value2_3];
            string[] arr3_3 = new string[value3_3];
            string[] arr4_3 = new string[value4_3];
            string[] arr5_3 = new string[value5_3];

            // Для получения значений равное 2
            int value1_2 = 2;
            int value2_2 = 6;
            int value3_2 = 10;
            int value4_2 = 14;
            int value5_2 = 18;
            string[] arr1_2 = new string[value1_2];
            string[] arr2_2 = new string[value2_2];
            string[] arr3_2 = new string[value3_2];
            string[] arr4_2 = new string[value4_2];
            string[] arr5_2 = new string[value5_2];

            // Для получения значений равное 1
            int value1_1 = 1;
            int value2_1 = 5;
            int value3_1 = 9;
            int value4_1 = 13;
            int value5_1 = 17;
            string[] arr1_1 = new string[value1_1];
            string[] arr2_1 = new string[value2_1];
            string[] arr3_1 = new string[value3_1];
            string[] arr4_1 = new string[value4_1];
            string[] arr5_1 = new string[value5_1];
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

            for(int i = 0; i < value1_3; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(i.ToString() + "%");
                arr1_4[i] = str;
                write_excel(arr1_4);
            }

            for (int i = value1_4; i < value2_3; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(i.ToString() + "%");
                arr2_4[i] = str2;
                write_excel2(arr2_4);
            }

            for (int i = value2_4; i < value3_3; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(i.ToString() + "%");
                arr3_4[i] = str3;
                write_excel3(arr3_4);
            }
        }

        public static void write_excel(string[] str)
        {
            try
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;
                ObjExcel.Visible = false;
                ObjExcel.UserControl = true;
                ObjExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
                ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Шаблон.xls");
                ObjWorkSheet = ObjWorkBook.Sheets[3];

                int iNums = str.Length;

                switch (iNums)
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[4, 4] = str[0];
                            break;
                        }
                    case 2:
                        {
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[4, 4] = str[0];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[5, 4] = str[1];
                            break;
                        }
                    case 3:
                        {
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[4, 4] = str[0];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[5, 4] = str[1];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[6, 4] = str[2];
                            break;
                        }

                    case 4:
                        {
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[4, 4] = str[0];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[5, 4] = str[1];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[6, 4] = str[2];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[7, 4] = str[3];
                            break;
                        }
                }

                ObjWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\Шаблон_Изменен.xls");
                ObjExcel.Quit();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public static void write_excel2(string[] str)
        {
            try
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;
                ObjExcel.Visible = false;
                ObjExcel.UserControl = true;
                ObjExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
                ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Шаблон_Изменен.xls");
                ObjWorkSheet = ObjWorkBook.Sheets[3];

                int iNums = str.Length;

                switch (iNums)
                {
                    case 5:
                        {
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[8, 4] = str[4];
                            break;
                        }
                    case 6:
                        {
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[8, 4] = str[4];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[9, 4] = str[5];
                            break;
                        }
                    case 7:
                        {
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[8, 4] = str[4];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[9, 4] = str[5];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[10, 4] = str[6];
                            break;
                        }

                    case 8:
                        {
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[8, 4] = str[4];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[9, 4] = str[5];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[10, 4] = str[6];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[11, 4] = str[7];
                            break;
                        }
                }

                ObjWorkBook.Save();
                ObjExcel.Quit();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public static void write_excel3(string[] str)
        {
            try
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;
                ObjExcel.Visible = false;
                ObjExcel.UserControl = true;
                ObjExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
                ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Шаблон_Изменен.xls");
                ObjWorkSheet = ObjWorkBook.Sheets[3];

                int iNums = str.Length;

                switch (iNums)
                {
                    case 9:
                        {
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[12, 4] = str[8];
                            break;
                        }
                    case 10:
                        {
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[12, 4] = str[8];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[13, 4] = str[9];
                            break;
                        }
                    case 11:
                        {
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[12, 4] = str[8];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[13, 4] = str[9];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[14, 4] = str[10];
                            break;
                        }

                    case 12:
                        {
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[12, 4] = str[8];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[13, 4] = str[9];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[14, 4] = str[10];
                            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[15, 4] = str[11];
                            break;
                        }
                }

                ObjWorkBook.Save();
                ObjExcel.Quit();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have solved my problem (An example of a console application)